# A 1g mass is suspended from spring. It is measured to exert a restoring force of 9 dynes when it is displaced 1 cm from its equilibrium position

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The first part of this problem is to find the differential equation governing the motion of this spring-mass system. Using the given the mass and the k (9dynes/cm) I thought that the differential equation would be y''-9y=0, but a similar example I have would mean that it would instead be y''+9y=0. Could someone let me know which one is correct and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latter answer is correct, i.e. $y'' + 9 y = 0$.

The restoring force of an extended spring has both a magnitude and a direction: $F = -k\, y$, where y is the displacement. The minus sign accounts for the fact that a mass attached to a spring displaced in the positive $y$ direction feels a restoring force in the negative $y$ direction and vice versa. The spring always wants to pull itself back to zero displacement.

Now, consider Newton's 2nd Law: $F = m\, a$. Here $F = -k\,y$, and $a = y''(t) = y''$. So $F = m\, a$ becomes $-k\, y = m\, y''$ or, equivalently (when m = 1 and k = 9 in the given units), $y'' + 9\, y = 0$.